# IUPAC-Naming of Dioxin

Tags: nomenclature

In the molecule 2,3,7,8-tetrachlorodibenzo-p-dioxin, the "p" means para--because each chlorine is para to an oxygen?
In IUPAC nomenclature shouldn't "para" be replaced by a number?

Comment: The IUPAC recommended name is given in the IUPAC Gold Book: `2,3,7,8-tetrachlorodibenzo[b,e][1,4]-dioxin`

Answer (score 8):

> In the molecule 2,3,7,8-tetrachlorodibenzo-*p*-dioxin, the "*p*" means para because each chlorine is para to an oxygen?

No. The *p* (for “para”) indicates the dioxine isomer.

> In IUPAC nomenclature, shouldn’t “para” be replaced by a number?

Yes. The preferred IUPAC name for this isomer is **1,4-dioxine.**

Therefore, the corresponding name of the parent structure of the compound that is given in the question is **2,3,7,8-tetrachlorodibenzo[*b*,*e*][1,4]dioxine.** The complete name is **2,3,7,8-tetrachlorodibenzo[*b*,*e*][1,4]dioxine.**

The preferred IUPAC name, however, is **2,3,7,8-tetrachlorooxanthrene.**